# meter export variable with var keyword

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript

I want to create `Meteor` project with `Typescript`.

I have a package written using typescript modules like this:

```
// a module
module p {
  export class Person {
    name: string
  }
}
```

This generates the js file:

```
var p;
(function (p) {
var Person = (function () {
    function Person() {
    }
    return Person;
})();
p.Person = Person;
})(p || (p = {}));


// package.js
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.addFiles('models.js');
  api.export('p', ['client', 'server'])
});
```

But AFAIK, meteor exports global variable. 
I know it may sound silly but is it possible to configure meteor to export the variable with `var` keyword?

Referencing my `p` module from `client` directory after manually removing `var` keyword is success but leaving as it is results `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Person' of undefined` error

Comment: *"But AFAIK, meteor exports variable without var keyword."* What do you mean? That first line, `var p;`, declares the variable, and that variable is initialized in the last line (`})(p || (p = {}));`) with the content of your module (or more accurately, with an object if it doesn't already refer to one, that's about to get the content of your module added to it inside the function). The end result is that that variable `p` will end up referring to an object with your module's stuff on it.

Comment: ok, first of all sorry if I mistaken here. But refereing to this https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/writing-a-package/#tmc-global-vs-local-variables
Did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you did. :-) What that's saying is that *inside your `module` block*, if you have any local variables, be sure to declare them so you don run into [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. It doesn't apply to anything in your example. The only thing it could really apply to would be `Person`, and `Person` is already local to the module.

Comment: Frankly, that section doesn't seem like great advice. It's telling you to use anonymous function expressions, and then warning you to be sure to put `var` in front of the variable names so they don't become implicit globals, but I don't see any reason why using function *declarations* (like the one meteor turned your `class Person` into) wouldn't be a better choice there anyway (and wouldn't have the problem of people forgetting the `var`).

Comment: *"Referencing my p module from client directory after manually removing var keyword is success but leaving as it is results undefined Person error"* Just to be clear, you don't want to do that. You want that `var` there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm experiencing the same problem, where I define a function assigned to a variable using the var keyword, and it breaks. I *also* want (really really want) the var keyword to be there. But it only works when I take it out. I'm not feeling very clear on why it has to be this way and I'm not crazy about continuing until I understand it. Do you know of any tutorials or the like that explain this better?

Comment: Ah, not sure how I missed this: *"Technically, Meteor helps us out a bit by wrapping all of our package code in an anonymous function, meaning our variables are automatically scoped to the current file and don’t leak out. However, it’s still wise to pop a var in front of any variable that isn’t intended to be exposed to the public."* -- I'm really not nuts about that because it forces you to write ugly/dangerous code.